# how do i select the first value of "for" loop within the for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I used following code to descending the degree value of a network, using networkx. Now I want to select only the fist value of the iteration whithin the same for loop. code as follows:

```py
for i in sorted(G.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    list_id=(i[0])
    print(list_id)
```

Output gives as follows:

```
264
32
19
4
101
15
```

Could you please tell me a way to select only the first value of this iteration, (i.e., `264`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you only want the max? Then no need to sort as this is more expensive than `max`.

```py
list_id = max(G.degree, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
for i in sorted(G.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    list_id=(i[0])
    break # add this line
    print(list_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [264, 32, 19, 4, 101, 15]
print(sorted(my_list).pop())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the values, you could store them, for example into a list, so you can use them as needed:

```
list_ids = []
for i in sorted(G.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    list_id=(i[0])
    list_ids.append(list_id)

list_ids[0]
```